# Replace a string before the user sees the page

Tags: php

I am trying to create a custom CMS, every page has a unique ID and on every page is a string (<--UNIQUEID-->) at the place where the CMS text has to come.

I am trying to replace that string with the text that is saved in a database for that page, but I can't get that to work. I am trying this with DOM documents.

I have this at the moment:

This is before the `<html>`tag:

`ob_start()`

And after the `</html>`> tag:

```
if ((($html = ob_get_clean()) !== false) && (ob_start() === true))
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    $dom->loadHTML($html); // load the output HTML

    /* your specific search and replace logic goes here */
    $StringToReplace = '<--754764-->';
    $ReplacementString = 'test';
    str_replace($StringToReplace, $ReplacementString, $html);

    echo $dom->saveHTML(); // output the replaced HTML
}
```

It is showing the page, but it's not showing the replacement string text.

Comment: Weird approach. DOM stuff seems pointless. Output buffer is a string, string functions work on strings. Skip the DOM stuff. Ideally take a step back and do the replacements further up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do two things and getting confused in the process.

When you load your HTML buffered output into a `DOMDocument` object (via `DOMDocument::loadHTML`), the state of that object is now the parsed HTML. You then replace your string into `$html` itself, and then output the HTML from the `DOMDocument`.

Due to the fact that by the time you get to your `str_replace` call, the inner state of the `DOMDocument` is independent from `$html`, that replace call effectively does nothing to it.

If you're certain that the comment will be of exactly that form, you can just `echo $html;` after the call to `str_replace`. This also saves you from having to worry about your output being compliant and parsing properly (`DOMDocument` is stricter than most browsers when it comes to that).

Answer (score -1):

The code you posted doesn't use the `DOMDocument` object to do any transformation of the document. It just parses the HTML then generate another one that is functionally identical to the original.

You just don't need the `DOMDocument` object.

The `str_replace()` does the expected transformation but the value it returns is completely ignored. You have to `echo` it in order to get the desired result.

The following code is enough:

```
if (($html = ob_get_clean()) !== false) {
    /* your specific search and replace logic goes here */
    $StringToReplace = '<--754764-->';
    $ReplacementString = 'test';
    echo str_replace($StringToReplace, $ReplacementString, $html);
}
```